# Apply checkBox in flutter with SFDataGrid

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

It's so difficult to find some documentations for flutter on internet, you are my last chance ahah

In my example, i create a simple grid with some data.

So, i want to use checkbox in flutter with SFDataGrid, my goal is :

- select rows
- if a row is selected, get the data
- Click on button and display the selected data

```
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class CheckboxColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckboxColumn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CheckboxColumnState createState() => _CheckboxColumnState();
}

class _CheckboxColumnState extends State<CheckboxColumn> {
  late EmployeeDataSource _employeeDataSource;
  List<Employee> _employees = <Employee>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employees = getEmployeeData();
    _employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employees: _employees);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter DataGrid')),
      body: SfDataGrid(
          source: _employeeDataSource,
          showCheckboxColumn: true,
          checkboxColumnSettings: DataGridCheckboxColumnSettings(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 0, 0),
          ),
          selectionMode: SelectionMode.multiple,
          columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
          columns: <GridColumn>[
            GridColumn(
                columnName: 'id',
                label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: const Text('ID'))),
            GridColumn(
                columnName: 'name',
                label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: const Text('Name'))),
            GridColumn(
                columnName: 'designation',
                label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: const Text('Designation',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
            GridColumn(
                columnName: 'salary',
                label: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: const Text('Salary')))
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource({required List<Employee> employees}) {
    dataGridRows = employees
        .map<DataGridRow>((dataGridRow) => DataGridRow(cells: [
              DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: dataGridRow.id),
              DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: dataGridRow.name),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                  columnName: 'designation', value: dataGridRow.designation),
              DataGridCell<int>(
                  columnName: 'salary', value: dataGridRow.salary),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
          alignment: (dataGridCell.columnName == 'id' ||
                  dataGridCell.columnName == 'salary')
              ? Alignment.centerRight
              : Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Text(
            dataGridCell.value.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ));
    }).toList());
  }
}

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);
  int id;
  String name;
  String designation;
  int salary;
}

List<Employee> getEmployeeData() {
  return [
    Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
    Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
    Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
    Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 10000),
    Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 20000),
    Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Manager', 25000),
    Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 35000),
    Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Designer', 45000),
    Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 10000),
    Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 30000),
  ];
}
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Nobody can help.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected rows through the **DataGridController.selectedRows** property. Please refer the below UG link,

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/selection#getting-selected-rows